# regular expression with hyphen in between numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I have to check whether the user entered string is in a particular format as below eg:

```
123-1234-1234567-1
```

ie after first 3 digit a hyphen, then after 4 digit another hyphen, after seven digit an hyphen then a single digit.

I used the below regular expression

```
@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{7})[-. ]?([0-9]{1})$"
```

It is working fine for above expression but it will also pass the expression without `-` also

```
eg:-  123-1234-1234567-1 //pass
      123123412345671    //also getting pass.
```

The second string should fail. What change i should do in the regular expression to achieve the same?

Comment: @downvoter can u please tell whats the issue in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
^\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{7}-\d$
```

If you want to allow dot and space also as delimiter then use:

```
^\d{3}[-. ]\d{4}[-. ]\d{7}[-. ]\d$
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..its simple and exactly what i needed always it will be digits seperated only by `-` but i don't know why somebody downvoted my question. Isn't it clear?

Comment: Your question was totally clear to me with your attempt clearly shown. Don't worry about a downvote from some trigger happy member.

Answer (score 1):

The problems is that you are having optional quantifier `?` after `[. ]`. 
Remove them, and it should work fine

```
@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]([0-9]{4})[-. ]([0-9]{7})[-. ]([0-9]{1})$"
```

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bI0hA5/1)

The `?` makes the preceding pattern optional as it matches 0 or 1 character. So in the second example the regex engine safely matches zero `-` to get to match the entire string

Comment: thanks for the answer..your option also woked for me thanks for the help..will upvote your answer.. but i don't know why somebody down voted my question. Isn't it clear?

Comment: @Sachu You are welcome. The question is really clear, but I have no idea why it was downvoted.